# What is the sum of finite, independently distributed negative binomials?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis

Suppose for $i=1,\cdots,k,$ that $X_i$ are independent $NB(r_i,p)$ random variables. Find the distribution of $Y=\Sigma^k_{i=1}X_i$.

My first instinct to solve this problem was to use multivariate transformations; however, after looking through my notes, I realized that I may be able to make use of the multinomial theorem here. However, I want to see if my mgf approach may work, since that is usually the cleanest attempt.

My work:

$M_Y(t)=E(e^{\Sigma^k{i=1}X_it})=\Pi^k_{i=1}M_{X_i}(t)$.

Since $M_{X_i}(t)=(p/[1-(1-p)e^t])^{r_i}$, then

$M_{Y}(t)=(p/[1-(1-p)e^t])^{\Sigma^k_{i=1}r_i}$.

However, I cannot identify a distribution based off of this mgf. Did I do something wrong, is this the wrong method, or am I just not seeing which distribution is identified by this mgf?

Comment: To my mind the simplest motivation for the answer is to consider the connection between the Bernoulli process and the negative binomial. The distribution of the sum of several independent NBs with fixed $p$ us immediately obvious (at least for the other parameter being integer); knowing that (and forming the obvious guess for the general case) should make it easy to see that its only going to be necessary to do the n=2 case since general $n$ follows by induction. You might then spot it more easily with the mgf or you might be able to get it by more direct means.

Comment: Thank you for this addition intuition!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression you get for $M_Y(t)$ is the MGF of the negative binomial distribution with parameter $r = \sum_{i=1}^k r_i$.